# How to get Eclipselink samples to work: "student" and "mysports" samples

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, sample

I've been trying to get the following Eclipselink samples to work, with less than 0% success:

A)
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPARS/Simple

B)
git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/eclipselink/examples/mysports.git

Both samples are quite recent and should work "out of the box". My results:
A) starts and deploys on glassfish, but application is totally unresponsive
B) does not deploy, since glassfish does not find the data-source mentioned in the persistence xml's: java:global/mysports

For both I tried to get information on how they are supposed to work, but after two days of searching for documentation, I can safely state: there is literally NOTHING documented.

For A) I am totally clueless, there is nothing to configure for this sample, but the provided URLs for interacting with the REST service always return with 404 and no log or error message whatsoever.

For B) Beside the broken data source (I guess my fault), I tried setting default JDBC data-sources, to see if at least the REST service itself works: it looks dead, I get exceptions when opening the sample JSF pages (the reference variables inside the pages all resolve to NULL).

Anybody ever tried to actually run these samples? I am totally frustrated after many hours of being far away to anything testable...

Maybe some questions as a starting point:
- How does the JPA-RS get registered in the appserver? how do I tell if it was at all? And which URL it maps to?
- How does this magic "java:global/mysports" data source work?
- The maven configuration acts funny, I couldn't get any of the two samples to properly debug (no breakpoints were hit at any point in time). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ladies. A friend of mine had the brilliant idea of forcing ALL logging on eclipselink-jpars library (by setting this value in every single file we could think of) and indeed we found an exception that is FOR NO GOOD REASON hidden in the lowest log level:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: eclipselink.json.include-root value: false
```

Whatever that means, but that again convinces me that I will not use this feature/lib for the time being. An exception should be visible on all log levels, especially if I go down to FINE (as stated in the samples!)! I almost lost three days just because of this.

Comment: EclipseLink JPA-RS leverages EclipseLink MOXy as the JSON-binding provider.  JSON binding was added to MOXy in EclipseLink 2.4.0, but GlassFish 3.1.2 contains an earlier version (hence the exception).  You will need to update the version of EclipseLink in GlassFish to 2.4.2 or 2.5.0 the following article will help you do that:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Comment: I added a comment about this in the other topic I opened after getting to know the exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838089/eclipselink-jpars-exception-eclipselink-oxm-xml-key-not-found

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  It will definitely help people encountering the same issue.  The good news is that starting with GlassFish 4.0 that extra configuration is no longer necessary.

Comment: One more question, since you seem to read comments :-) : do you know how this magic "java:global/mysports" data source can work, even if not registered at the app-server? This sounds like a more broad concept, but I never used anything else than traditional jdbc data sources.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Glassfish earlier than Glassfish 4.0 (http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0/promoted/) you will need to download newer version of EclipseLink 2.4.2 binaries from  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php (2.4.2 Nightly Build Results) and replace following files under $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules with corresponding jars you downloaded above:

- org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar
- javax.persistence.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar

Make sure you clear Glassfish osgi cache by removing the $GLASSFISH_HOME\glassfish\domains\your_domain\osgi-cache directory after you replaced the bundles listed above, and before you restart the Glassfish.

Answer (score 2):

These are both advanced examples, unless you are looking for these specific features, I would recommend starting out with simpler examples.

There are many EclipseLink JPA examples documented here,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples

Most of the examples are still in SVN here,

http://dev.eclipse.org/svnroot/rt/org.eclipse.persistence/trunk/examples/

For documentation on the JPA-RS examples see,

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA#JPA-RS

Try adding question to the example's wiki discussion page if you are having specific problems.

The MySports example is very advanced.  Unless you are looking for extendable entities and multi-tenancy, I would not recommend starting with this example.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the wiki there. Anyway the samples that I tried are basically the "simple" versions (Student sample) already. The JPA stuff itself works for each sample and is not really interesting for me, the extended features such as the RS-part is what I am looking for. But I will probably not go for it, as I am very nervous about the lack of "debug-ability" atm. I just want to understand my problem and learn from it for the future (and stay with JAX-RS for a while).

Answer (score 1):

To add to James' comments, if you are specifically interested in JPA-RS, perhaps these additional comments will help.  I also recommend asking questions on the wiki discussion page.

JPA-RS gets registered in the appserver by the existence of the org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_[version].jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory.  This jar contains the web-fragment.xml which is what defines the JPA-RS service.  You will know if it was deployed if the following URL pattern returns persistence unit metadata:

```
http://<server>:<port>/<applicationName>/persistence
```

Some additional documentation for JPA-RS:
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/restful_jpa001.htm
- wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/2.4.0/JPA-RS/REST-API

One thing that will help you debug is to view the Glassfish server log.  If you are running in Eclipse, right click on your Glassfish server in the Server view, go to Glassfish->View Log File, which will open the server log in your console view.  This will show you what is happening with deployment, and will alert you to any errors.  Also be sure to double check your URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to debug the samples as much as I can, but the funny thing is: there are neither errors nor anything that would make me think the jpa-rs service is working. For a sample app I would have expected to see some log or similar output (just for clarity/learning). Since non of the tested samples work, I think it has something to do with my particular setup... BTW: JPA/Entities in each sample could be access via EJB/Entity-Manager (I modified them for that purpose afterwards). As a side-effect I think I am the fastest known sample-deployer now (in the universe) :-).